# Angular ng-model not updating model

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a beginner working on my first Angular/Ionic project. Basically, I have a form that I ask the user to fill and submit. On clicking the submit button, I want the information entered to be made into a JS object and stored in the API. But, no matter what the user inputs, the object values are showing to be undefined.

Here are the files.

**appApi.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('appApi', function() {

    var data = [{
        "fName": "Subscription",
        "desc": "Guitar Learning Session",
        "selfExpiryDate": "3/20/2015",
        "selfExpiryTime": "18:15"
    }];

    var getData = function() {
        return data;
    }

    var addData = function(newData) {
        data[data.length] = newData;
    }

    return {
        getFavors: getFavors,
        addFavor: addFavor
    };

});
```

**controller.js:**

```
.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'appApi', function($scope, $state, appApi) {
    $scope.newData = {
        "fName": $scope.fNameForm,
        "desc": $scope.descForm,
        "selfExpiryDate": $scope.selfExpiryDateForm,
        "selfExpiryTime": $scope.selfExpiryTimeForm
    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        appApi.addData($scope.newData);
        $state.go('app.home');
    }
}])
```

and **form.html:**

```
<ion-view ng-controller = "formCtrl">
    <ion-content>
        <div class = "list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" ng-model = "fNameForm" placeholder="Favor Name" autofocus>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" ng-model = "descForm" placeholder="Favor Description">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" ng-model = "selfExpiryDateForm" placeholder="Favor Expiry Date">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" ng-model = "selfExpiryTimeForm" placeholder="Expiry Time">
            </label>
        </div>

        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click = "submit()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I am not sure if the way I am trying to update data dynamically is even right. Can someone tell?

Also, I want the user to be re-directed to the home page once he submits the form. Is the way I have done it correct? My url changes but the view doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use `$scope.newData` in controller, then you should use this object for corresponding `ngModel`'s:

```
<div class="list list-inset">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newData.fName" placeholder="Favor Name" autofocus="" />
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newData.desc" placeholder="Favor Description" />
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newData.selfExpiryDate" placeholder="Favor Expiry Date" />
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newData.selfExpiryTime" placeholder="Expiry Time" />
    </label>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dQ7160A8BK99FfGMbzwS

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, make sure your capitalization is all matching:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fvu3hb7R8srRh2ynPrGL?p=info

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  FormCtrl = function($scope, $state, AppApi) {

    $scope.submit = function() {
        AppApi.addData($scope.newData);
        $state.go('app.home');
    };
};

AppApi = function() {

    var data = [{
        "fName": "Subscription",
        "desc": "Guitar Learning Session",
        "selfExpiryDate": "3/20/2015",
        "selfExpiryTime": "18:15"
    }];

    var getData = function() {
        return data;
    };

    var addData = function(newData) {
        data[data.length] = newData;
    };

    return {
        getFavors: getFavors,
        addFavor: addFavor
    };

};



  var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
  myApp.factory('AppApi', AppApi);
  myApp.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'AppApi', FormCtrl]);

})();
```

Since you have one app, one controller, and one factory-- the way you are loading everything will work-- when you get into more than one controller and factories and whatnot (you are only allowed to define one app, that is so you don't make one of my rookie mistakes)

A larger example you can see working is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wTIo8y6Det9Y5VLP86pM

Comment: What does encapsulating everything within a function() do?
Also, when does it make sense to make multiple modules?

Comment: I am about to edit my answer to include dfsq's comment about the ng-model misalignment with accessing the data in the addData method.

But before I do that, an example showing multiple modules was linked at the bottom-- since it isn't directly related to the problem, I have not included the source. Also the anonymous function wrapper I quietly advocated, (function() { }), is one of a few ways to prevent other scripts clobbering anything I am trying to do and some modest protection of other javascript from me.

Comment: Found it! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression The wrapper closure function is called this because of it's special case usage.